# VLOOKUP Name Error even after using formula wizard

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, microsoft-excel-2019, dropdownlist

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure what is wrong in by VLOOKUP formula. I even used the formula wizard to try to fix it.

Here is the formula I'm using.

```
=VLOOKUP(A10,Melaminedetails,2,FALSE)
```

Cell A10 is a dropdown list.

Below are some visuals of the worksheet and the formula wizard.

[image: Clip of worksheet]

Clip of formula wizard

[image: Clip of formula wizard]

Comment: How about changing the Table array to be `I5:M11`?

Comment: I put them in manually cuz if I select it, excel gives me the cell names, but unfortunately it still didn't work.

Comment: `Melaminedetails` is spelt correctly, is valid as a named range and is scoped correctly (Workbook, or the sheet if everything is on the same sheet)?

Answer (score 0):

#### Find the Error

Most of us would presume that the formula is sound but that the lookup value cannot be found.  For example, there may be an extra space or another typo.  Since we can't tell what is in the cells from an image, you will need to do your own testing.

The formula itself seems sound.

<sub>**Sample Formula Working**</sub>
[image]

You could do a simple test like changing your lookup value to something simple like `"bob"` and also adding `"bob"` in the table.  Does the formula now complete successfully?

My first suspect would be your lookup list.  Was the list built in isolation from the actual values in the table?  In other words, in my example, if you make a change in column `E`, is it automatically propagated to the list in `B2`?  If not, then that is an obvious place to start looking for issues.

In my example, my lookup list is auto-populated from the range `E2:E7`.  This saves me time and most importantly insures that my lookup values will necessarily have a matching value in the lookup column.

<sub>**List from Actual Values**</sub>
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Played around with it and finally managed. Took a few hours.

Comment: Excellent!  The experience of solving this will help you in the future.  Maybe you'll be answering other people's questions one day!  I started off like you 4 years ago. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)